# One function for addition/subtraction in "Clock arithmetic"/congruent math?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

I want to "mix" char* data in this form:

```
source = (source + some_primary_number) % 256;
```

--the 256 line is because of I need to keep the range of char.

so I can do the "mix" and "un-mix" in 2 functions - the implementation above is for the mixing and this one is for the un-mixing:

```
source  = source  - some_primary_number;
if ( source  < 0)
{
    source  = 256 + source 
}
```

This works, of course. But is there any option to do the mixing and un-mixing with the same function?

I remember something fuzzy with congruent math...

Can you help me please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure this is what you mean, but in general, in **modular arithmetic**, subtracting a particular `x` is the same operation as adding `m - x`, where `m` is the modulus (here, 256).

So for example if your 'mixing' is adding 47 (mod 256), then 'unmixing' is adding 209 (mod 256), because 209 = 256 - 47.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of mixing are you looking for? What is your intended use of the mixing / un-mixing?

From a pure point of view, if the mixing and un-mixing can be done with the same function and the same primary number, then it means that each output number is paired with exactly one input number.

I can think of XOR with a constant as one example of being its own inverse function.

[Linear congruent generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) usually require a different un-mixing (inverse) function.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any option to do the mixing and un-mixing with the same function?

```
int foo(int source, int some_primary_number)
{
    return (source + some_primary_number) & 255;
}
```

To unmix, simply call it with a negative number. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Why did the modulus change?  Of course it will hold for any modulus.

Comment: @Ben: Whoops, confused `%` with `&` :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to get at, but I think this may be what you want:

```
x = ( ((a + b) % M) + M ) % M;
```

This will compute the common residue of `a + b` modulo `M`; it always result in a number `[0..M)`.

It works by first computing `(a + b) % M`, then `+ M` just in case it's negative, and then `% M` again.

Comment: Why not just `( a + b + M ) % M`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to do arithmetic modulo 256.  C and C++ support that with unsigned arithmetic, so if you cast to `unsigned char *` you can simply do the obvious math.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `source` to have type `unsigned char`, everything should just work. (Or `uint8_t` if you want to be more explicit about the size, but `uint8_t` cannot exist on platforms where `CHAR_BIT!=8` anyway.)

One possible pitfall is if you'll be using the value of `source+blah` in an expression without first writing it back into a variable of type `unsigned char`. In this case, it could very well be outside the range of 0-255 due to integer promotion. If you need to do that, either case the result of the addition back to `unsigned char` or mask it with `&0xff` (or equivalently `&255`).

By the way, don't listen to people who tell you to use % instead of &. Unless you're very careful to make sure the expressions you use with % are of type `unsigned int` or a larger unsigned type, % will incur an actual division/remainder operation as opposed to just bit masking. People mess that up all the time, thinking the compiler will optimize % by a power of 2 and not realizing that the optimization is impossible for signed types.